# Illegal immediate error in assembly code - wrong direct addressing?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I don't understand why I get an error in this assembly code. I want to assign the byte 0Ah at the memory location with address 0100h (in the data segment). I get the error "illegal immediate" at line 6 but I believe the direct addressing I am using is fine - I saw similar examples in some texts.

```
.MODEL small
.DATA
.STACK
.CODE
.STARTUP
    MOV Byte Ptr[0100h], 0Ah

    MOV AH, 4Ch
    INT 21H
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to mention which assembler you are using. In general, that addressing mode indeed exists but the syntax may vary depending on the assembler.

Comment: Looks like masm/tasm. You probably need to add the segment. Try `MOV Byte Ptr [ds:0100h], 0Ah`

Comment: You forgot a placeholder in the data segment: `DB ?` and for the stack segment some more bytes too.

Comment: @DirkWolfgangGlomp Default stack in masm/tasm (16-bit targets) I believe is 1024 when a value isn't specified.

Comment: I forgot to mention I use TASM. MOV Byte Ptr [ds:0100h], 0Ah works, thanks. 
I thought [0100h] would it be the same of ds:[0100h] and of [ds:0100h]. Are there different versions of assembly where this could be right or did I get it totally wrong?

Comment: Different assemblers will have different syntax, so it all depends. You might have been reading about NASM or GNU Assembler which have differences.